# How to find and extract all duplicated subsets inside an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have this array which contains two subsets 7,8 and 1 two times:

```
[
  [1,2],
  [9,10,7,8],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [1]
]
```

How can i find and extract all the subsets (contained more than one time, i.e. other than itself) inside this array and get following result?

```
[
  [2],
  [9,10],
  [7,8],
  [5,6],
  [1]
]
```

The subsets are always contiguous, i.e. 9,7 should be not considered as a subset of 9,10,7,8.

**EDIT:**
The order of the final array it does not matter, but the items shall be like in the starting array:

```
  ok=[               ok=[            notOk=[
      [2],               [9,10],            [10,9],
      [9,10],            [2],               [2],
      [7,8],             [5,6],             [6,5],
      [5,6],             [1],               [1],
      [1]                [7,8]              [8,7]
    ]                  ]                   ]
```

Any non recursive solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why `1` is missing in the first item?

Comment: Why isn't `[1,2]` a subset when `[9,10]` and `[5,6]` are? Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what qualifies a set of numbers as a "subset".

Comment: Apparently `[1]` is a subset, so it should be removed from `[1, 2]` (I think?)

Comment: Is `[1,2]` same with `[2,1]` ?

Comment: @passion: i can't assume [1,2] is the same as [2,1] when [2,1] would be in the final resulting array

Comment: @deblocker What if instead of `[5,6,7,8]` you have `[7,5,6,8]`?

Comment: why is `[1]` at the end and `[7, 8]` in the middle?

Comment: The question is unclear : it seems that taking [[1], [2],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9], [10]] fits all your requirements.

Comment: @NinaScholz: please see my edit

Comment: @NenadVracar: the subset 7,8 would be not found in [7,5,6,8] - this is already in my question.

Comment: What output is expected for `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`? Should it be `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3]]` or `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [1]]` or neither?

Comment: @trincot: good catch, until now, i never encountered in my test data this situation, but i can't exclude that. So, i can't answer right now, as i don't know yet which drawbacks this would be cause. However, i will keep your useful comment in mind. THX

Comment: I suppose neither, since in both proposed solutions, there is still overlap of values, and thus only `[[1],[2],[3]]` would satisfy? Also, is it just coincidence that your example data has incremental values? I suppose if you had `[9,104]` instead of `[9,10]` it would not influence the way the arrays are split, right?

Comment: You edited the question to ask about "duplicated" subsets that are "contained more than one time", yet your desired output includes `[2]` and `[9,10]` and `[5,6]` even though each appears only once.  The criteria you're trying to apply are still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this solution which builds a map (hash) for each distinct value, providing for it an array of occurrences. Each such array element provides the sub-array (from the input) in which the value occurs, and its index in that sub-array.

In a second step the successors of equal valued elements are compared. If those also are all the same, and that value does not occur anywhere else (i.e. with a different predecessor), then it is concluded that the successor value should be kept joined with the preceding value. When this happens, the next successors are tested to see if maybe an unbroken triplet can be formed, ...etc.

In the code below I have used different input data than provided in the question, as this solution produces different output for it compared to what the other solution (posted before mine) produces for it.

The code uses ES6 syntax:

```js
var input = [
  [1,3],
  [9,11,7,12,2],
  [5,0,7,12,2,8,10,7,12,2],
  [1]
];

// build hash (map)
var hash = input.reduce ( (hash, arr) => 
    arr.reduce ( (hash, val, index) => 
        // Collect the array element's references in a Map keyed by value: 
        hash.set(val, (hash.get(val) || []).concat({ arr, index })),
        hash 
    ), new Map() // initial value of the hash is an empty Map
);

var result = Array.from(hash, ([val, matches]) => {
    var match = matches[0];
    // Compare the sucessors of the elements that are equal
    for (var offset = 1; match.index + offset < match.arr.length; offset++) {
        var valAtOffset = match.arr[match.index+offset];
        // If the sucessor values only occur as successor of the preceding value, 
        // and all these successors have the same value, then keep this value together
        // with the preceding value:
        if (hash.get(valAtOffset).length !== matches.length ||
            matches.some( match => match.arr[match.index+offset] !== valAtOffset )) break;
        // Remove the hash entry for the value that is now part of this unbroken sequence
        hash.delete(valAtOffset);
    }
    return match.arr.slice(match.index, match.index+offset);
});

// output:
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map for the common items. Delete from the map the items with a single count, use the map for building first the common result set. Then use the rest for the result set, after checking if common, then return or check if continuous, the append to last result set, or add a new array to the result set.

```js
var data = [[1, 2], [9, 10, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1]],
    result = [],
    common = new Map;

// get all items and store the occurence
data.forEach((a, i) => a.forEach(b => {
    if (!common.has(b)) {
        common.set(b, []);
    }
    common.get(b).push(i);
}));

// keep only occurence of more then one
common.forEach((v, k, m) => v.length === 1 && m.delete(k));

// get common keys, sort and push single or contiguous elements to the result set
[...common.keys()].sort((a, b) => a - b).forEach((k, i, kk) => {
    var l = kk[i - 1];
    if (l === k - 1 && common.get(l).toString() === common.get(k).toString()) {
        result[result.length - 1].push(k);
        return;
    }
    result.push([k]);
});

// push non common items to the result set
data.forEach((a, i) => a.forEach(function (b, i, bb) {
    var l = bb[i - 1];
    if (common.has(b)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!common.has(l) && l === b - 1) {
        result[result.length - 1].push(b);
        return;
    }
    result.push([b]);
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Could you please kindly explain the reason for the sorting in `[...common.keys()].sort`?

Comment: they might be not in ascending order. it's necessary, because of the continguous need of the values to group.